# Campaign registration creates duplicates - can I over come it?

Tags: campaign, form

I am looking for a way to integrate a campaign registration form on our website, but if a user, that is already a contact registers, it will NOT be created as a new lead, but instead, create a new oppty, that is related to the correct : Account, user and campaign.

Using a web to lead, if you assign the campaign ID, how can you solve, that if the new registrant is already a contact, it will not be created as lead?

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can validation incoming Web to Lead forms to detect when the information on the form is either incomplete, bogus, or the same as (or similar to) an existing contact and/or account before it's inserted as a new Lead. If a match to a contact is found, you can fire other workflow or run a trigger to update an existing contact or do something else based on the form.

If that should happen, you'd have several options:

- You could simply create a Task for the owner of the Contact to create
  a new Opportunity on the Account and associated it with the Campaign
  using workflow.
- Run a VisualFlow trigger or use Process Builder (essentially to build
  one) that creates the new Opportunity for you and associates it with
  the Campaign.
- Call a class that creates a new Opportunity for the Account which you
  can associate with the campaign.